# fancyBox 2 not loading inline content

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

On a development site here: http://dev.pathway-360.com/about-us/

I am trying to load some inline content, but it isn't working.  I have added an image to test that FancyBox is loading and the fact that it load would indicate to me that it isn't a more general problem and that it is only inline content not working.

I have seen a number of other people asking a very similar question, but their fixes don't seem to help here.

My HTML is:

```
<a class="various" href="#inlinedata">Inline</a>
<a class="various" href="http://dev.pathway-360.com/wp-content/themes/pathway360/images/ballwitharrows.jpg">Image</a>


<div id="inlinedata" style="width: 500px; display: none;">
    Just text
</div>
```

And my JS is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".various").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '70%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you receive some console output when triggering the first link?

Comment: No, nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a second event listener on the click event.  Removing this solved the issue.